# Which .NET Version is installed on this host?

Tags: .net

I am trying to figure out which .NET version it is that runs on this particular host. I am getting contradictory results:

- ASoft .NET Version Detector says **4.6.2**
- Registry key says "Release" "394802", which maps to **4.6.2** according to [how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)
- However, `mscorlib.dll` and `clr.dll` have version **4.7.2117.0**, while some other files in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` have version **"4.6.1586"** (e.g. csc.exe).
- `Environment.Version` returns **4.0.30319.42000**

Here is a screenshot summarizing that information.
[image: Screenshot]

Here is the full log of ASoft Version Detector:

```
<32Bit>
2.0.50727.8745
->C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
4.7.2117.0
->C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

<64Bit>
2.0.50727.8745
->C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
4.7.2117.0
->C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

< Installed .NET Frameworks >
.NET FW 2.0 SP 2  (CLR:2.0)
.NET FW 3.0 SP 2  (CLR:2.0)
.NET FW 3.5 SP 1  (CLR:2.0)
.NET FW 4.6.2  (CLR:4.0)

< Installed Updates >
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile 
KB2468871
KB2468871v2
KB2478063
KB2533523
KB2544514
KB2600211
KB2600217
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended 
KB2468871
KB2468871v2
KB2478063
KB2533523
KB2544514
KB2600211
KB2600217
KB2468871
KB2468871v2
KB2478063
KB2533523
KB2544514
KB2600211
KB2600217

< Installed Languages 3.0>
English - United States
< Installed Languages 3.5.x>
English - United States
< Installed Languages 4.x>
English - United States
```

I am wondering which .NET version it is, that is really installed? How can it be that the registry "Release" key does not match "mscorlib.dll" version? Is the installation corrupted?

If the registry "Release" key is not reliable, what's the most reliably source of information to determine the .NET/CLR version?

Comment: You can have different versions of .net installed side by side.

Comment: File versions are rarely relevant. Why are you even looking at them? And what started this hunt in the first place, i.e. why don't you trust what tools/registry are telling you. @HamletHakobyan - not different versions within a CLR version. You can only have one 4.x installed (from a runtime perspective. You can have plenty of targetting packs/SDKs but that's irrelevant here)

Comment: Right. All 4.X installations are in-place updates. So, they cannot be side-by-side. It's important for me to know the correct .NET version, since I am trying to test my product against all available .NET releases. On this particular host, I am not sure, what I am testing against.

Comment: There have been many 4.6.2 versions, deployed through Windows Update.  Those 4.7 DLLs no doubt sneaked in through a security update.  That doesn't always pan out well btw.  This month's update is notable, it [caused trouble](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/07/20/advisory-on-july-2018-net-framework-updates/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you have .NET Framework 4.6.2 installed, precisely what the tools and registry told you.

Furthermore, you have [this update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4074880/description-of-the-security-and-quality-rollup-for-net-framework-4-6-4) (or later) applied, which is how you wind up with the 4.7.2117.0 version number for some files.<sup>1</sup>

[`Environment.Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version(v=vs.110).aspx) always tries to tell you what *CLR* version you're on:

> For the .NET Framework Versions 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.5.2, the Environment.Version property returns a Version object whose string representation has the form 4.0.30319.xxxxx. For the .NET Framework 4.6, its point releases, and the .NET Framework 4.7, it has the form 4.0.30319.42000.
>
> **WARNING**
>
> For the .NET Framework 4.5 and later, we do not recommend using the Version property to detect the version of the runtime;

---

<sup>1</sup>I had no foreknowledge of this update. I just searched on `mscorlib 4.7.2117.0` and this was the first result.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Looks like a hot trace. According to "Version Detector" (I've added the log to my question) that KB is not installed, but of course it could be part of another KB.